# Sending an Outlook invitation from Gmail

Tags: gmail, notifications

Someone asked me to send them an Outlook invitation. I'm not on Outlook and don't want to set up an email account just to send them an invitation.

Is there a way to send an Outlook invitation from Gmail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific invite for an Outlook user within the default Gmail interface. Since you can [send a calendar invitation within Gmail](http://mashable.com/2010/04/15/gmail-calendar-invitations/) now testing the behavior of Outlook should be trivial.

Generally speaking varying clients such as Outlook, Lotus Notes, Thunderbird, etc... acknowledge the invites from a differing client; however in some cases they don't.

Based on information from [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-help-bugs/browse_thread/thread/59ede88c5ddba2ac) it appears that at least towards the end of 2007 they stopped working; going from Gmail to Outlook.

The best option is to simply send a standard calendar invitation within Gmail to see how Outlook responds.

Comment: That is a nice new feature, and seems to work great with Windows 7 and Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this by creating an event in my Google Apps Calendar to my Outlook 2010 calendar at work. It successfully came through as a calendar invite, and upon accepting, it was added to my Outlook calendar, Google calendar and the acceptance response email was received in the GMail.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-platform invitations (Outlook to Google / Google to Outlook) are both problematic for similar reasons.

Recipient must click an email to add the event to their calendar (rather than it showing up as an invite directly in the calendar). Moreover, if it is a one-off event with no changes, this is generally painless. However, any edits or cancellations that the organizer makes to the event will *not* necessarily result in an email to the cross-platform recipient, and almost certainly will not render as a cancellation in the destination calendar, thus resulting in stale events. If you have an office 365 account (note you do not need to use outlook client for this) it is possible to use the the Outlook API to generate an outlook-based invite:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0

If you wire that Microsoft API together with Google Apps Script you could theoretically mirror both the original event and its changes, propagating the original invites and their updates in the appropriate format. It is astonishing that something like this isn't easier.